# R language - how to list variables in use

Tags: r

How can I generate a list of all the variables that have been assigned in an R language session?

Comment: Since this doesn't involve actual computations, it is off-topic here.  It is likely better suited for the R forums or StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm more inclined to keep it here for now, if it gets answered, because I believe it would fall under the header of "Software packages or languages used in computational science". If we get enough questions on R language syntax, then we can talk about migrating & clarifying our scope. I also agree this question would also be answered well on an R forum. Given our current traffic, I'd rather be permissive, build community, and narrow scope later with more data (and traffic) than exclude what looks reasonable for now.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness of the answer, you can use `ls()` to list all the assigned variables and data frames. This is similar to `who` and `whos` in Matlab.

If you want to get the list data.frames only you can use something like this:

`ls()[grepl('data.frame', sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))))]`

You should probably ask questions like this on R forums.

Comment: I did not know about the R forum. Thanks!

Comment: Basic programming questions are better off for [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (43055 questions with R tag). [Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) has a lot of R-related material from the stats point of view (4984 questions with R tag).

Comment: Thank you very much. I stumbled upon this rich trove of knowledge so I am mapping my way.